# Where can I find in Angular which template will be shown when application is runned?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular-template

I'm using Angular 4 and I've received project from my friend, and when I run a command:

`ng-serve -o` some view is opened, that view/template is in project called:

```
main-screen.component.html
```

And here is whole component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-screen',
  templateUrl: './main-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-screen.component.css']
})
export class MainScreenComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I saw that conent from `main-screen.component.html` is loaded when app is runned - because I edited it to make sure that's right template, but I don't know where is set that `main-screen.component.html` will be shown when app is runned, because I would like to show another template for example `main-screen-blue.component.html`

Thanks!

Cheers!

Comment: Can you search in the project? Try to look for: `Routes = [`

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app.module.ts` in your src directory and locate:

```
@ngModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

The find the import statement of your AppComponent (can be named differently), just find the `bootstrap` property and you will find which component gets initialized on app load.

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
```

The above tells that the first component to load is `app.component` in the same directory in which you find `app.module`. This component will have a `templateUrl` located in the `@Component` decorator which will tell you the location of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Routing between components and deciding which component to show on startUp is quite easy.

Create a separate module as app-routing.module.ts and there give the routes for your app like

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: MainScreenComponent }] //this shows the page on startup
```

The detailed explanation for routings can be found on
[Angular Routing](https://angular.io/guide/router)